# how to let class of an <i> tag not change when the page reloads

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

i created an ajax favorite button where when a user clicks the heart button the information gets sent to the server without reload and the heart shape becomes filled with red using javascript(exactly like instagram heart button ). now i am having a problem that when the page reloads the heart filling is removed and how will each indiviual message be filled and not only the first instance ?

here is my code:

my html code:

```
   <a href="" class="msg-icon" onclick="toggle()" >

        <input  type="hidden" name="fav"  value="<?php echo $row['msgid']; ?>" style=""  >

        <i class="far fa-heart" id="favBtn" style="" ></i>
   </a>
```

my javascript code:

```
  function toggle(){
var btn= document.getElementById("favBtn");
if(btn.classList.contains("far")){
    btn.classList.remove("far");
    btn.classList.add("fas");
}else{
    btn.classList.remove("fas");
    btn.classList.add("far");
  }
}
```

how can i make it that the heart filling is only removed when the user clicks on the button again for each message?

Comment: Explanation of how this should work and what the specific problem is is hard to follow

Comment: What's the difference between `far` and `fas` ? Code should be readable.

Comment: @charlietfl lets say i have many messages, each message has a favorite button. when a user clicks on the button the heart becomes filled until the user clicks the button again. and when he clicks any message it becomes filled, not only the first message. because i am using document.getElementById("") which only retrieves the first instance. how can i do this?

Comment: @gregn3 far is the outlined heart shape, fas is the filled heart shape. its a font awesome class

Comment: Pass `this` into toggle() function in the html then query for that specific child `<i>`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @charlietfl can you be more specific with what i should add in my code?

Comment: `onclick="toggle(this)"`  ....  `function toggle(element){ var btn = element.querySelector('i.fa-heart');...`

Comment: @charlietfl thank you so much, your answer solved my issue!!!! really i appreciate it!!!!

Comment: @charlietfl one last question if i may, how can i let the class of the <i> tag remain the same until the user clicks again on the button. because as it is now it only stays filled until the page is reloaded

Comment: You need to store the state of each one either on server or in localStorage. Then use that state to set the appropriate class when page reloads. Also means each one will need a unique identifier to track it's state by

Comment: @charlietfl noted, thank you so much for the great help.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using PHP to load the id of the message on page load. I'm guessing you want something similar when setting the initial CSS-classes on "favBtn". The following snippet checks a field on the same $row with php and chooses chat class to show initially based on that.

```
<i class="<?php if($row['isFavorite'] {echo "fas";} else {echo "far";}) fa-heart" id="favBtn"></i>
```

Another alternative would be to load the data with an AJAX call, but that would delay the load of the status and probably not what you are looking for in this case.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If those unreadable CSS class names come from an external library, consider putting them into variables with more recognizable names, and using the variables instead of the external names directly.

For example:

```
var heartOutline = 'far'
var heartFilled = 'fas'

function toggle(){
    var btn= document.getElementById("favBtn")
    if(btn.classList.contains(heartOutline)){
        btn.classList.remove(heartOutline)
        btn.classList.add(heartFilled)
    }else{
        btn.classList.remove(heartFilled)
        btn.classList.add(heartOutline)
    }
}

// they got rid of semicolons in JS because they wanted to emulate Python
```

I'm getting used to not using semicolons in JS.

Comment: I will keep that into consideration, but do you have any idea how to make the class not revert back when the page reloads? For instance when user click it becomes filled until the user clicks again and it stays filled even after the page reloads

Comment: @ChrisJamal I would use AWS DynamoDB on the server to save the state of the buttons. For ajax requests when saving, save the buttons state data into the DB. When loading a page in PHP the first time, read the buttons state data from the DB, and add it to the HTML. So already on page load in PHP you know if the button is pressed or not, and add the corresponding CSS class to the button. Create a unique ID if you have multiple buttons. Example:`<?php $id = 'favButton1'; $pressed = $db->get($id); echo '<i class="' . ($pressed ? 'fas' : 'far') . ' fa-heart" id="' . $id . '" style="" ></i>';`